# How to make a data validation to accept only whole number if next cell contains certain text

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a table like this :

[image]

When I select a product with data validation in column B I get automatically the unit in column F

For example I type Product 1 in B3, and in F3 I get "Kilo" , if its product 2 I get "Piece"

What im trying to do is:
If F3 <> Kilo (meaning is piece, box etc), in D3 to allow only whole numbers, but if F3 = "Kilo" then allow decimal numbers as well

And I need this to apply for the entire column

---

Also im tryng to format column D based on F
if F3 = Kilo then have a format like "#.##"
But if F3 <> Kilo to have only the format as "##" without decimals, only 1,3,7, 15, 30 etc

---

I have been looking for a solution but I don't get it

Any help please ?

Comment: Could you maybe share an example sheet to get a grasp of what are you doing. Would you be comfortable with an Apps Script solution to your problem? I don't know if there is an straight way to do this without Apps Script using only the conditional formatting rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=((F2="pz")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(""&D2, "\.|,"))))+(F2<>"pz")
```

[image: 0]